# NVM install node won't change NPM global modules root folder

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Hi I've just upgrade Node to v9.3.0 and copied my NPM global modules from the last installed version:

```
nvm install 9.3.0 --reinstall-packages-from=9.2.0
```

But when I do

```
npm root -g
```

It still says

```
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules
```

How do I upgrade Node with NVM and automatically change NPM global modules root folder to the latest version as well?

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

`nvm install 9.3.0 --reinstall-packages-from=9.2.0` should certainly install 9.3, install 9.2's global packages, and then "use" 9.3.

However, that won't change the default. Assuming the install command worked, `nvm use 9.3` should, for that shell session, set you up.

`nvm alias default node` will always use the latest available node version when you open a new terminal.